# Magento2.3 : Pagination - jump to top of pagination at PLP page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, jquery, pagination, product-detail-page

I have a problem with Buttons in Pagination. If the user clicks the button, it reloads the page with loader and settles down at the current page scroll position. Is there any method to forcefully load to jump to the top of the page?

The code I have tried so far is

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('a.action.next,a.action.previous,li.item.current,li.item a.page').click(function() {
          setTimeout(function(){    
                jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
          }, 6000);           
    });
    
});
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on("click", 'a.action.next,a.action.previous,li.item.current,li.item a.page', function(event) { 
          setTimeout(function(){    
                jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
          }, 6000);           
    });
    
});
```

Note: 3000 = 3 second. Adjust 3000 according to your need.

Comment: Hi, @Chirag thanks for the reply back, tired your code still no success. It's on the same page and still not moving up.

Comment: Adjust 3000 according to your need. try 5000. You are getting late reply from server response so.

Comment: adjusted to 6000, on the first click time alone it's working on any class after second or third click it's not working the same issues is arsing.

Comment: @ScriptHost, Please try updated answer.

Comment: Have updated the code, please check and let me know.

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111790/discussion-between-script-host-and-chirag-rajput).

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:-

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        require(['jquery'], function (jQuery) {
          jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('#cpa-scroll-to-desc').click(function (event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".box-collateral").offset().top - 120}, 'slow');
            });
          });
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: Can you describe with my class

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this code in list.phtml and it works perfectly

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        jQuery("ul.pages-items a").each(function(index) {
            jQuery(this).click(function() {
                jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");         
            });     
        }); 
    });
</script>
```